# timestamp off by minutes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

This one's got me flummoxed.  I've got a little mysql file holding users' last logins.  One of the fields is date_time.  It correctly holds the date_time. (Example:  2016-02-10 13:15:59 ) When I fish the date_time back out, however, the time is off, usually pointing to the next hour with the minutes showing :03 or :01

Here's the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT date_time FROM the_file where user_fk = " . $user_id ." LIMIT 1";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row=$db->fetch_array($result); 
if ($result){
    $date_time=$row['date_time'];
    $timestamp = strtotime($date_time);
}
```

Later, in a js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var year_test = '<?php echo date("Y",$timestamp); ?>';
year_test !=="1969" ? $('#login_div').html('<?php print ("Last login: " . date("l, F jS, Y g:h A",$timestamp)); ?>') : '';
</script>
```

The time and date appear, correctly formatted in the div, but as I've stated the time is never correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date` format repeats the hour part of the time by using `g` and `h` - perhaps you intended `i` there? Try

```
date("l, F jS, Y g:i A",$timestamp)
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> - `g` 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros
> - `h` 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
> - `i` Minutes with leading zeros

Comment: Yes! Of course!!  I spent so much time dickering with the php that I forgot to look at the format.  Nothing like a fresh pair of eyes on a problem.  Thank you.